# ¿ Como unir dos ArrayList en un uno solo para retornar,?

Tags: java

Buen dia.
Estoy realizando un metodo que me trae datos de una vista que tiene tabla usuario y tabla vehiculo en mysql, tengo los get y set de usuario y vehiculo en clases diferentes y necesito retornar una sola lista con los datos que estan en los dos arralistm, como podria hacer esto.

```
public List listVehiculos() {

        List<CVehiculo> listvh = new ArrayList<>(); // Lista datos vehiculo
        List<CUsuario> listus = new ArrayList<>(); // Lista datos del usuario
        List<String> unionlistas = new ArrayList<>(); // Lista para unir los dos listas usuario y vehiculo
        try {
            conn = cn.getConexion();

            CallableStatement vehiculos = conn.prepareCall("{ CALL Vh_ListVehiculos() }");

            rs = vehiculos.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                CVehiculo vh = new CVehiculo();
                CUsuario us = new CUsuario();
                // Datos del vehiculo que se muestran en tabla
                vh.setVhplaca(rs.getString(1));
                vh.setVhmodelo(rs.getString(2));
                vh.setVhmarca(rs.getString(3));
                vh.setVhestado(rs.getString(4));
                vh.setVhprecio(rs.getString(5));
                vh.setVhcategoria(rs.getString(6));

                listvh.add(vh);

                // ==== Datos del usuario
                us.setUsnombres(rs.getString(7));
                us.setUsapellidos(rs.getString(8));
                us.setUstelefono(rs.getString(9));
                us.setUseremail(rs.getString(10));

                listus.add(us);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return listvh; // Aca retornar una sola lista unida con las de us y vh
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para combinar listas puedes usar el método `addAll` de la siguiente manera:

```
listvh.addAll(listus); // Agregar los elementos de listus a listvh
return listvh; // Y después retornar la lista
```

Comment: asi no me deja , ya lo habia intentado

Comment: Qué resultado o error te da?

Comment: @Angelita, no se deja porque `CVehiculo` y `CUsuario` son tipos incompatibles, intenta haciendo que `listvh` contenga `Object` en vez de `CVehiculo`, `List<Object> listvh` de ese modo la solución planteada por @CIOC va a funcionar.

Comment: También podrías crear una clase (o interfaz) padre vacía y hacer que `CVehiculo` y `CUsuario` extiendan de ella, así esas dos clases serán compatibles y crear tus listas con esa clase padre para que pueda recibir cualquiera de los dos tipos `List<ClasePadre> listvh` y `List<ClasePadre> listus`

Comment: @JohnnyTB y como deberia retornar los datos y en el listvh.add ?? porque lo hice asi pero me funciono pero solo me lista un objeto el segundo no lo lista.

```  List<Object> listvh = new ArrayList<>();   listvh.add(vh);
                listvh.add(us); ```